# Why won’t iCloud Keychain sync my passwords?

Tags: icloud, keychain, mobile-safari

I have set up two-factor authentication for my Apple ID and turned on iCloud Keychain. To test whether it backups my passwords, I turned it off and chose *delete from iPhone*. Then I turned it on and looked at my passwords, but nothing was there. I’ve tried many several times, but it seemed iCloud Keychain won’t store my passwords.

I think it might be because I turned it off, rather than signed out of my Apple ID, or it might be something wrong with my iCloud configuration.

Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: I have lost a year of password history cause I turned off keychain on iPhone. I have 10.12.6 running with keychain. It deleted my passwords that were saved using Macbook!

Answer (score 1):

If you have no other Apple devices, then when you chose to delete your passwords, you likely deleted them from your phone (at first).  But when you re-enabled iCloud, you synced your current phone status to iCloud, which is / was password-less and removed the content from iCloud as well.